# difference between C++ template partial specialization for function and functor

Tags: c++

I have been using C++ template class partial specialization for function argument for a while. I was surprised to find that the same syntax could be used to partial specialize functors.

In the case 1 below, it is easy to see F(T) is a function type. Since it is a type, it could be used to substitute the template parameter, however in case 2, the semantics of F(T) is changed, it is not a type but still can pass the compiler and work.

I googled a few hours, but not found too much valuable info in this regard. Could anyone explain why case 2 worked?

```
template<class> struct func; 

template<class F, class T>
struct func<F(T)>              //1. this is a partial specialization for function
{                              //with signature F(T)
   using type = F(T);
};

template<class> struct ftor;
template<class F, class T>
struct ftor<F(T)>              //2. Is F(T) a type?
{
   using type = F;
};

struct foo {
  void operator()(int) {}
};

int main() {    
    //1 void(int) is a function signature
    cout<<typeid(typename func<void(int)>::type).name()<<endl;
    //2 what is foo(int)?
    cout<<typeid(typename ftor<foo(int)>::type).name()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is. `foo(int)` is the type of a function which takes an `int` and returns a `foo`. Whether or not `foo` is a functor is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2 cases, `F(T)` is a signature of function taking `T` and returning `F`.

You may rename your class `func` by `identity` and `ftor` by `result_of` and `F` by `ReturnType` to better match naming/implementation.